# Algolia: show location based results within a certain boundary of radii around you

Tags: geolocation, algolia

All my items have GeoLocation data stored in algolia.
I want to query items that are between for example 15 and 30 km away.
Atm, I only see an option of specifying a central point and then defining a radius around that point. Meaning I also get results under 15 km away.

```
    const searchParams = {
      aroundLatLng: `${latitude}, ${longitude}`,
      aroundRadius: 30000,
      facetFilters: [],
      hitsPerPage: MAX_PAGE_SIZE
    }
```

Maybe something can be done with some geo specific filters (? if that exists)

```
filters: `distance >= ${15000}`,
```

How can I query for items that are between the circumferences of two location based circles (in this example inner circle radius: 15000, outer circle radius 30000)

Answer (score 0):

Algolia's geoSearch capabilities don't currently support complex geometric shapes like rings.

I could think of two ways to accomplish something close to this:

1. Create the shape using a series of polygons (https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/how-to/filter-results-inside-a-polygonal-area/)
2. Perform queries at both the inner and outer radius, then remove and records that appear in both result sets.